# jquery form validation for one input with multiple custom messages

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-form-validator

I am using jquery formvalidator. I want to show multiple custom messages for one input box.

If I add single custom message for one input it works fine but for multiple it is not working.

Please guide me how to do that?

Comment: so you want one input box to have multiple custom messages? is there a reason for this?

Comment: It is required field, should accept only numbers and should have min length.

Answer (score 0):

'$.formUtils.addValidator({
    name : 'requiredCouponCode',
    validatorFunction : function(value, $el, config, language, $form) {
      if(value.length == 0) return false;
    },
    errorMessage : 'Coupon code can not left blank.',
    errorMessageKey: 'badcc12'
  });

$.formUtils.addValidator({
    name : 'couponCodeLength',
    validatorFunction : function(value, $el, config, language, $form) {
      console.log(value.length);
      if(value.length < 5) return false;
    },
    errorMessage : 'Coupon code should be of minimum 5 characters.',
    errorMessageKey: 'badcc'
  });'

I am using above code but it is taking one at a time and not both.

Answer (score 0):

you can use different validation error message on a input field
e.g.

```
data-match-error="your message"
data-error="fill out this field"
data-minlength-error="4  characters required"
```